# client.wait_for timeout issue

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a car game with discord.py and I want to make the player shift with a quick reaction time using the reactions in discord but, when tried anything below 1 second (even 0.75) timeout for `await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=timeout)` doesn't listen normally for the reaction instead when I double click it ,it works . I want it to listen how it normally does.

(I ran it in a loop and tried so it can't be that my reaction time is slow)

Comment: could you improve your question title please?

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try, `await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=0.75, check=check)` But I can't help more than that since I don't have the full code.

And this site could be helpful: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html